# Deref coercion seems applied even if there is no type mismatch

Tags: rust

I have some confusion about Deref coercion. I read that Deref coercion is used implicitly when there is a type mismatch.

consider following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = X;
    let r = &x;
    r.show(); // prints referenced
}

trait Tr {
    fn show(&self);
}

struct X;

impl Tr for &X {
    fn show(&self) {
        println!("referenced");
    }
}
```

the above code prints `referenced`.

now add new trait implementation on owned type:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = X;
    let r = &x;
    r.show(); // prints owned
}

trait Tr {
    fn show(&self);
}

struct X;

impl Tr for &X {
    fn show(&self) {
        println!("referenced");
    }
}

impl Tr for X {
    fn show(&self) {
        println!("owned");
    }
}
```

now it prints `owned` but I am expecting it to print `referenced`.

since `&X` implements trait `Tr`, there is no type mismatch. so it should not be derefed implicitly.

is there some thing wrong in my understanding. I also found no way to get it printing `referenced` after adding new `Tr` implementation other than using generics with trait bounds.

Comment: looks like I have look at the show method signature rather than impl line. after some fiddling found that `(&r).show();` prints `referenced`

Comment: @FZs actually, the doc you linked states that the compiler will try `T` first, then `&T` and `&mut T` before going to `*T`, `&*T` and `&mut*T` (see the `Box<[i32;2]>` example), so here it should try `&X` first…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `Tr::show` takes a `&self`. This means that `<&X as Tr>::show: Fn(&&X)`, whereas `<X as Tr>::show: Fn(&X)`. There is actually no deref coertion involved at all. Basically, by adding a borrow yourself, you are doing what deref coertion would do.